# Color insertion from the biggest value

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

So I'm working on the cohort analysis, creating a table from the database, and having a trouble when it comes to coloring. I'm not an expert at javascript, so I dont really know how to do it.

So for example, I have 10,2,6,4.

And then in the table, I wanted to give a coloring from the biggest value.

like

```
10 => Darkest Green
2 => Lightest Green
6 => Dark Green
4 => Light Green
```

So if we sort it to make it easier,

```
10 => Darkest Green
6 => Dark Green
4 => Light Green
2 => Lightest Green
```

Edit:
The 4 number above just a raw example, I'm doing a monthly cohort, which means I will have 12 number, and it will be random, and many months will also have 0, which means it will be white/super light green.

How can I do that? Thanks a lot, and sorry for my english

Comment: have a try `colorArray.sort((a,b)=> b-a)`

Comment: What are the total, maximum & minimum values in this range? Also how many colours do you wanna support?

Comment: @VishwasChauhan There are no maximum, but the minimum is 0. There will be monthly cohort, so lets say I have 12 coloumn, that means 12 different green color.

Comment: @prasad I'm really sorry, but I dont get it.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an array with high priority of colors to low. like:

`$colors = array( "Darkest Green", "Dark Green", "Light Green", "Lightest Green" );`

now you can use 'foreach' in php to assign that color. like:

```
$i = 0;
$new_result = array();

foreach( $cohort_result as $row ) {

    $new_result[ $row ] = $colors[ $i ];
    $i++;

}
```

Regards.